# Radio Button Handler not firing properly

Tags: radio-button, extjs4, handler

I have a set of 6 radio buttons : All , Time, Suppression, Address , Session and Tags.

I have a handler associated with each button that fires an event on it being clicked. The handler will fire a grid filtering event and load only certain portions of a grid depending on what radio is selected.

Example of a radio button code.

```
{

    boxLabel: 'Source',
    name: 'source',
    inputValue: 4,
    handler: function () {
        gridstore.clearFilter();
        gridstore.filter('id', '2');
        gridstore.load();
    }
}
```

The first time I click the radio, the handler loads and works properly displaying the right part of the grid for each of the 6 radios but if I try to fire it again (come back to an already clicked radio and click on it again), it doesn't work. I am sure I need to send some parameters to the handler. Can someone help me with what they should be?

EDIT: This is my entire code for that section

```
var radioGroup = {
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    // title: 'Radio Groups',
    layout: 'anchor',
    height: 250,
    border: false,
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%',
        labelStyle: 'padding-left:4px;',
        border: false
    },
    collapsible: false,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        // fieldLabel: 'Single Column',
        columns: 1,
        border: false,

        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'All',
            name: 'all',
            inputValue: 1,
            border: false,
            checked: true,
            id: 'All',
            handler: function () {
                var all = Ext.getCmp('All');
                if (all.getValue()) {
                    gridstore.clearFilter();

                    gridstore.load();
                }
            }
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Time',
            name: 'time',
            inputValue: 2,
            id: 'Time',



            handler: function () {
                var time = Ext.getCmp('Time');
                if (time.getValue()) {
                    gridstore.clearFilter();
                    gridstore.filter('id', '3');
                    gridstore.load();
                }
            },



        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Assignment',
            name: 'assignment',
            inputValue: 3,
            id: 'Assignment',
            handler: function () {
                var assignment = Ext.getCmp('Assignment');
                if (assignment.getValue()) {
                    gridstore.clearFilter();
                    gridstore.filter('id', '5');
                    gridstore.load();
                }
            }
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Source',
            name: 'source',
            inputValue: 4,
            id: 'Source',
            handler: function () {
                var source = Ext.getCmp('Source');
                if (source.getValue()) {
                    gridstore.clearFilter();
                    gridstore.filter('id', '2');
                    gridstore.load();
                }
            }
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Address',
            name: 'address',
            inputValue: 5,
            id: 'Address',
            handler: function () {
                var address = Ext.getCmp('Address');
                if (address.getValue()) {
                    gridstore.clearFilter();
                    gridstore.filter('id', '5');
                    gridstore.load();
                }
            }
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Supression',
            name: 'supression',
            id: 'Supression',
            inputValue: 6,
            handler: function () {
                var supression = Ext.getCmp('Supression');
                if (supression.getValue()) {
                    gridstore.clearFilter();
                    gridstore.filter('id', '6');
                    gridstore.load();
                }
            }
        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Tags',
            name: 'tags',
            id: 'tags',
            inputValue: 7,
            handler: function () {
                var tags = Ext.getCmp('tags');
                if (tags.getValue()) {
                    gridstore.clearFilter();
                    gridstore.filter('id', '7');
                    gridstore.load();
                }
            }
        }]
    }]
};
```

Updated Code 2:

```
var radioGroup = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {


    //defaultType: 'radiofield',
    // title: 'Radio Groups',
    layout: 'anchor',
    height: 250,
    border: false,
    defaults: {
        anchor: '100%',
        labelStyle: 'padding-left:4px;',
        border: false
    },
    collapsible: false,
    items: [{
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        // fieldLabel: 'Single Column',
        columns: 1,
        border: false,
        listeners: {
            change: function (name, newValue, oldValue) {
                alert('new value is ', newValue);
            },

        },

        items: [{
            boxLabel: 'All',
            name: 'all',
            inputValue: 'all',
            border: false,
            checked: true,
            id: 'All',

        }, {
            boxLabel: 'Time',
            name: 'time',
            inputValue: 'time',
            id: 'Time',

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to combine them into one radio group, so only one of them will be selected. Then your event handlers will be fired again and again.

Update: first of all change all your handler to be like this:

```
handler: function(radio, checked) {
   if (checked) {
      // Do filtering
   }
}
```

Don't do getCmp and don't create additional and not used variables. Everything you need is already sent to the handler. Also you might want to add `console.log(radio)` before `if (checked)` to see if the handler is in fact being called second time.

And remove

```
name: xxx
id: xxx
border: xxx
```

from each radio button definition.

Update2: Try to add listener to RadioGroup itself:

```
listeners: {
   change: function(el, newValue, oldValue) { console.log('new value is ', newValue); }
   scope: me
}
```

Update3: Make something like this (see example http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#!/api/Ext.form.RadioGroup)

```
Panel
  -- RadioGroup
  --- listeners {}
  --- items: [
  ----- Radiobutton
  ----- Radiobutton
  ----- Radiobutton
      ]
```

Comment: I placed an alert to see if it was being fired and the second time around it doesn't pop...So I'm guessing its not getting fired? What could be the reason for that?

Comment: Does the value get changed? do you see just one selected radio box and it's moving around when you're clicking through them?

Comment: Yup...everything works perfect the first time around. The second click and subsequent clicks on each radio is the issue. I have a feeling the handler signals are getting mixed up or some other handler is picking up the signal meant for another handler and then discarding it without any action.

Comment: Try to add one listener to the 'change' even for whole radiogroup, and not do this individually.

Comment: Can you give me an example of the params this listener would take?

Comment: The listener doesn't fire at all. The newValue is not getting set. So the alert displays as "The new value is :" for all the radios!

Comment: Updated in the main post. Please check!

Comment: No exactly. Keep Radiogroup, inside add listeners property, then items and each item is Radiobutton. See Update3 and sencha sample

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8806/discussion-between-user890928-and-sha)

Answer (score 1):

The handler event looks at the change event. If you click an already checked radio it will not fire because nothing changes. There is no click event. Something that I am missing very much.